# OSMnx gives "TypeError: query must be a string or a list of query strings" on basic use

Tags: python-2.7, osmnx

After following the instructions for installation of [OSMnx](https://geoffboeing.com/2016/11/osmnx-python-street-networks/) (including explicitly installing `spatialindex`) with

```
brew install spatialindex
pip install osmnx
```

running the very first basic example of

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('Manhattan Island, New York City, New York, USA', network_type='drive')
ox.plot_graph(ox.project_graph(G))
```

in the project's [readme](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/master/README.md), I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Rax/Documents/Projects/Coding/Python/maps/test.py", line 23, in <module>
    G = ox.graph_from_place('Manhattan Island, New York City, New York, USA', network_type='drive')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/osmnx/core.py", line 1850, in graph_from_place
    raise TypeError('query must be a string or a list of query strings')
TypeError: query must be a string or a list of query strings
```

How do I get OSMnx to run past this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be caused by having

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

in your code, [since](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/185#issuecomment-406876591) including it turns all strings to type `unicode`, while the API expects arguments of type `string`. If that is present, removing it will prevent the error from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

See also: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/185

> OSMnx is compatible with Python 2 and 3, so you don't need to import from the future package to use it. If you use Python 2 and import unicode_literals from future, all of your strings will be of type unicode instead. As you can see in the documentation, graph_from_place expects the query to be of type string, not of type unicode.